# swift: can't fetch entity-members from coredata

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, fetch

I am new to programming and started with swift (xcode 9.4.1, swift 4.x) recently. Probably the solution is quite easy, but I don't get it. There are some similar questions and answers in the www but they have different code and I don't know how to adapt it. So I would like you to help me out. Thank you!

I have an iOS-app which saves statistics in sports. I created two entities called Stat and Game. Saving works so far with this code:

```
@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let stats = Stat(context: context)
    stats.action = action
    stats.playerNumber = Int32(playerOfAction)
    stats.points = Int32(pointsOfAction)
    let statsMinute = Game(context: context)
    statsMinute.minute = Int32(currentMinute)
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
```

Now I want to fetch and display the last saved stat (and be able to edit it afterwards).
I am trying it with this code:

```
   func lastStatInfo() {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    do {

 let loadMin = try context.fetch(Game.fetchRequest()) as [Game]
        lastStatMinuteLabel.text = "\(loadMin.minute)th minute"
    } catch {
        print("didn't load minute")
    }
    do {
        let loadStat = try context.fetch(Stat.fetchRequest()) as [Stat]
        lastStatActionLabel.text = loadStat.action
        lastStatPlaylerLabel.text = "# \(loadStat.playerNumber)"
    } catch {
        print("didn't load stat")
    }
}
```

There are three errors like 
`'Value of type '[Game]' has no member 'minute''.`
Why aren't the attributes accessible? I think it's because the stats are stored as an array.
How do I fetch the data correctly?

Bonusquestion: I tried different types for my datamodels attributes. For saving jerseynumbers and points only Int32 does seem to work. Can you tell me why and if its the best way to store them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fetch request returns an array as the result (even if only one object exist) so you need to loop the array or only get one from a specific index

```
for stat in loadMin {
    var minute = stat.minute
    //do stuff with minute
}
```

Or

```
if !loadMin.isEmpty {
    lastStatMinuteLabel.text = "\(loadMin[0].minute)th minute”
}
```

I usually only use Int for integer values.

Comment: thank you. the loop works. hope I can adapt it to the other cases I need. There is no way to use Int because in xcdatamodeld you can choose ether Int16, Int32 or Int64. And the last times I tried it didn't work with Int16 (but I can't explain this).